# How to import a folder with multiple ".csv" files using Get Data (Power Query) on Microsoft Excel 365 in a Mac?

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-365

I am new to using Excel. I am currently working on a Case Study (Cyclistic) where I have multiple ".csv" files located in a desktop folder, that I want to import to one workbook in Microsoft Excel 365.

While searching online, it seems that it's very easy to do (Image 1). However, in the Microsoft Excel 365 that I am using on my Macbook, there is no Get Data > From File > From Folder. This option doesn't show in my Excel (Image 2).

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZpol.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUsRc.png)

I tried the option: Power Query Editor > Get Data > Text/ CSV (Image 3) but it doesn't allow me to import the folder, I can just import one .csv file at a time, while I want to import all files in order to merge them in one worksheet and clean the data.

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcSCH.png)

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUsJ5.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In windows, the code would be as below, and you'd paste it in home ... advanced editor ... within the powerquery environment.  You can try on mac

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Extension] = ".csv"),
#"Added CSVdata" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CSVdata", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content])), type table),
#"Added Custom" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added CSVdata", "Custom", each let name = [Name] in Table.AddColumn([CSVdata],"SourceFile", each name)),
#"Combined CSVdata" = Table.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Custom])
in #"Combined CSVdata"
```

I'd suggest reading in a single file yourself to see how a mac sets up the Source syntax

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just tried it. I got an error: Token Eof expected. What I have done is I took your code and pasted it with one modification: let Source = Folder.Files("/Users/nabilbenaissa/Dropbox/My Mac (Nabils-Air.Home)/Documents/Case Study Course 8 Cyclistic Bike-Share in Chicago/CSV files"),

Comment: Honestly - and for my personal stuff, I am on a Mac as well - anything Excel is so limited on a Mac that I found it worth it to invest in a Windows machine just for that purpose. Problem solved. They are never going to build it out like the Windows version, and to me the hassle is just not worth it.

Comment: I'd suggest reading in a single file yourself using the built in code generator to see how a mac sets up the Source syntax.  My example works as written in windows

Comment: Tried all that you said. It seems that Excel 365 on Mac lacks many options that won't allow me to import all .csv files into one workbook. Anyway, thanks a lot.